# distance to object as single value per instance

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

I have an array of lights and want a wave to run across it. Each light should only show one value.

Using the distance method below, I end up with a smooth gradient.
Is there any smart way of achieving this effect with just a single value per light, and not a gradient?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by updating to a Blender Version above 3.1 and using a capture attribute node with the domain set to instance.

[image]

Comment: If anyone has a solution for Blender 3.0, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Why are you using 3.0? Update to 3.3 which is the LTS version.

Comment: Because it means fixing some shaders, which I wasn't prepared to do.